# How to automate access token in soap ui

Tags: automation, soapui, access-token

I have created test cases in soap ui. I have to pass access token for each test steps and have added it.

I want to know is there any way to pass access token dynamically? For now what I am doing is getting access token every time by running login POST request and put manually in header of every test case and test steps.

I know that there is project level properties can by used but still it require one time manual to get access token and put in project level properties. I want to automation it like each time login test case run automatically and generated access-token should apply for all test cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can automate the whole process:

1. Make a POST request to get the access token.
2. Use a [Property Transfer test step](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties.html) to assign the token value to a project property (e.g. *myProperty*).
3. Use the project property in your requests as:

   `${#Project#myProperty}`

You can put this string into your JSON/XML, into HTTP headers or other places -- where you need it.

Comment: Do I need Soap UI PRO to access this property transfer feature? I don't get it in open source version.

Comment: `Property Transfer` type test step is available in Open Source edition of SoapUI

Comment: @Rao - Thanks just found.

Answer (score 0):

Property transfer worked for me.

You can also use, first get an access token by post request and from response transfer it to the test suite level by property transfer. And in every request, you can use in the header by providing:

```
Authorization: Bearer ${#TestSuite#token}
```